Is there a way of deleting TOP(N) rows in BigQuery?
Let's say I have two duplicated keys in a BigQuery table:
|--------'id'|
|   ab3212zxc|
|   ab3212zxc|

and I want to DELETE only 1 row.
Is there a way of use something like DELETE LIMIT 1 in BigQuery such as we can use DELETE TOP(N) in SQL Server?

One of the options would be to create a new table:
CREATE TABLE my_new_table
AS
SELECT * 
FROM my_old_table
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id) = 1

Official docs about removing dulicates - link

Can you try adding this SubQuery to your DELETE query SELECT fieldName FROM tableName WHERE FieldName = "ab3212zxc" ORDER BY fieldName ASC LIMIT 1; Just change the sample names to your details.
